# how to use json data in website, what kind of database should I use?

Tags: python, json, database, web

I am trying to create a website in which a visitor can click a state on the US map and have it provide them statistics and information about the candidate that ran in the selected state's election in a given year.
I already have an image map and I will add a javascript function that takes the year and the district as arguments.

I am trying to do this in Django and Google App Engine and I mainly code in Python.

I have gathered data in a .json file thinking that I can do something similar to `open("path.json", "r")` in Python and parse the data.

But I am not quiet sure how do it to or whether its even possible to do such thing. As I did some Googling, I am starting to wonder if I need to use a database. Should I use a database and if I have to, RDB or NoSQL? In addition, how should I feed the data in json to the database.

My json file looks something like this:

```
{
  "AL": {
    "api_version": "1.0",
    "pagination": {
      "count": 7,
      "pages": 1,
      "per_page": 100,
      "page": 1
    },
    "results": [
      {
        "party": "REP",
        "last_f2_date": "2015-12-09",
        "election_districts": [
          "00"
        ],
        "load_date": "2018-02-17T09:16:20+00:00",
        "party_full": "REPUBLICAN PARTY",
        "first_file_date": "2015-12-09",
        "office": "S",
        "incumbent_challenge": "C",
        "district_number": 0,
        "office_full": "Senate",
        "candidate_status": "N",
        "active_through": 2016,
        "candidate_id": "S6AL00336",
        "state": "AL",
        "election_years": [
          2016
        ],
        "federal_funds_flag": false,
        "incumbent_challenge_full": "Challenger",
        "flags": "S6AL00336",
        "district": "00",
        "cycles": [
          2016,
          2018
        ],
        "last_file_date": "2015-12-09",
        "has_raised_funds": true,
        "name": "BOWMAN, MARCUS",
        "operating_expenditure": 770.0,
        "primary_votes": "[19707]",
        "primary_sahre": "[0.0253026573760578]",
        "general_votes": "[' ']",
        "general_sahre": "[' ']"
      },
      {
        "party": "DEM",
        "last_f2_date": "2015-04-03",
        "election_districts": [
          "00"
        ],
        "load_date": "2018-02-17T09:16:20+00:00",
        "party_full": "DEMOCRATIC PARTY",
        "first_file_date": "2015-04-03",
        "office": "S",
        "incumbent_challenge": "C",
        "district_number": 0,
        "office_full": "Senate",
        "candidate_status": "P",
        "active_through": 2016,
        "candidate_id": "S6AL00302",
        "state": "AL",
        "election_years": [
          2016
        ],
        "federal_funds_flag": false,
        "incumbent_challenge_full": "Challenger",
        "flags": "S6AL00302",
        "district": "00",
        "cycles": [
          2016,
          2018,
          2020
        ],
        "last_file_date": "2015-04-03",
        "has_raised_funds": true,
        "name": "CRUMPTON, RONALD (RON) STEVEN",
        "operating_expenditure": 33668.0,
        "primary_votes": "[153897]",
        "primary_sahre": "[0.560802119355885]",
        "general_votes": "[748709.0]",
        "general_sahre": "[0.358672615888139]"
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend building a database as I find it easier to write code for it, especially if your data constantly changes. If it doesn't, it still will be a good idea as you can pull data from a database and upload data through python(example: psycopg2 for PostgreSQL).

In addition, your data will be growing every time there is an election, then more data will be added, making your JSON file expand and will need to write specific code to read such file if any stats are introduce. In comparison to a database, you can add a new field (which may not exist now) and give a default value to all entries, without having to copy the new value to every entry in your JSON file. Furthermore, querying data is simplified due to Django's framework.

Lastly, I will start with PostgreSQL as it is free and has a GUI interface to interact with it to help you better understand SQL.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You claim to be coding in Python with the Django Web Framework.

Django is a web framework specifically designed for database interaction (makes little sense to use it without one, if that is even possible). Django supports only relational databases (RDBs) and of those available, only:

- PostgreSQL (which Django docs recommend for production servers):

  - https://djangodeployment.com/2016/12/23/which-database-should-i-use-on-production/
- MySQL,
- Lightdb and
- Oracle

NoSQL databases are not officially supported by Django itself. There are, however, a number of side project and forks which allow NoSQL functionality in Django, like Django non-rel - [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/faq/models/#does-django-support-nosql-databases)

In Python it is easy to parse JSON format strings:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

And what you do with the result is entirely up to you and how it best fits in with your web site's general design and back end implementation. You could even store the JSON directly in a dedicated database field:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField